# Why my click event handler is (YES "is") working?

Tags: javascript, html

I know it's a bit funny because people often ask for a solution to something that is not working, in this case it's the exact opposite.

I was playing around with JavaScript and I discovered something that puzzled me!
I tried searching for help online but I can't find anything useful of the subject.

The problem is this: After calling a function `bar` only once, the `onclick` event is working perfectly fine. How is that possible!?

But when I ask for type of variable `x` it returns `undefined` instead of `Number`, which is normal, because `x` is inside `bar`.

```
function bar() {
    var p = document.getElementById("foo");
    p.onclick = showAlert;
    var x = 5;
    alert("bar function was called !");
  }
  bar();
```

Can anyone enlighten me what is exactly happening, a detailed explanation would very appreciated.

Full code: (JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ge4gj5nw)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #foo {
        border: solid blue 1px;
        width: 30%;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="foo">My Event Element</p>
    <p>Click on the above element..</p>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  function bar() {
    var p = document.getElementById("foo");
    p.onclick = showAlert;
    var x = 5;
    alert("bar function was called !");
  }
  bar();
  function showAlert(event) {
    alert("onclick Event detected!");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking here. Are you asking why the event handler is called? Or how the given scopes work here? Or are you asking why `showAlert` is available?

Comment: JavaScript is a garbage collected language.A variable or an object gets garbage collected when it is not in further use. This is done by looking at the execution context of that variable.

Comment: Function declarations are hoisted in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though `p` is scoped to the bar function `getElementById` will return a reference to a node in the DOM (which is of higher scope). By calling `p.onclick = showAlert;` you are mutating the `onclick` attribute (higher scoped) from within that function.

> After calling a function "bar" only once, the "onclick" event is
>   working perfectly fine.. How is that possible?

**Its possible because the invocation of `bar` mutates a higher scoped object.**

```
var global = {specialKey: 'I am global scoped'}

function testingFunctionScope() {
    global.specialKey = 'Not function scoped!';
    console.log(global.specialKey); // Not function scoped!
}

testingFunctionScope(); 
console.log(global.specialKey); // Not function scoped!
```

Comment: " Its possible because the invocation of bar mutates a higher scoped object. "
Sir you are addressing exactly what I'm looking for :)
Last question: What is the scope of the variable "p" ? ( global? )

Comment: `p` is only available within the scope of `bar`. This means the value of p (as assigned by bar) will always be throw a reference error outside of `bar`. Glad to be able to help!

Comment: Is the "higher scoped object" the mouse click event ?

Comment: After digging deeper into the subject and rereading you answer everything make perfect sense now :)
Thank you for help sir!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I know what you don't understand and I've prepared small piece of code to illustrate. It doesn't matter where you use p.onclick when function gets binded there it will stay throughout the lifecycle of DOM element or until you unbind the function.
Check this:
https://jsfiddle.net/52wq4gdv/1/
I set handlers and remove them depending on button pressed

```
// set vars globaly for ease of use.
var p = document.getElementById("foo");
var buttonRemove = document.getElementById("remove-handler");
var buttonAdd = document.getElementById("add-handler");

function bar() {
  p.onclick = showAlert;
  buttonRemove.onclick = removeOnClick;
  buttonAdd.onclick = addOnClick;
  var x = 5;
  alert("bar function was called !");
}
bar();

function showAlert(event) {
  alert("onclick Event detected!");
}

function addOnClick(event) {
  p.onclick = showAlert;
}

function removeOnClick(event) {
  p.onclick = undefined;
}
```

and html:

```
<button id="foo">My Event Element</button>
<p>Click on the above element..</p>
<button id="remove-handler">
  Remove on click handler
</button>
<button id="add-handler">
  Add back on click handler
</button>
```

This url should clear some things:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Answer (score 0):

When the 'bar' function is called, it updates the onclick property of the 'p' element. That property remains set until the page is refreshed and then the 'bar' function needs to be called again for the property to be set. The scope of the 'onclick' property for the link is the life of the page. It is global to the page.

'x' is a local variable and its scope begins when it is declared and ends when the function ends. Outside the function, the page is not aware of the variable 'x'.

For more information, lookup global variable vs. local variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "hoisting" and in your example it is hoisting precedence that functions are accessible before the variables declaration. I suggest you to read about what is hoisting in JavaScript.
Regarding the variable x it is "closures". You trying to call variable "x" from another function if I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick Event is working because within the bar function you set the onclick param of the element.

```
var p = document.getElementById("foo");
p.onclick = showAlert;
```

You can move those two lines outside of the bar function and get the same effect without having to have the separate function.

```
var p = document.getElementById("foo");
p.onclick = showAlert;

function showAlert(event) {
   alert("onclick Event detected!");
 }
```

This is all you would need in the script tag.

When the element is clicked, the showAlert function is called.